# PostGIS with Postgresql 9.5 beta1

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I have to switch to recent beta version of Postgresql for OS X (now it is 9.5 beta 1) and my current project needs PostGIS. I've installed the latest version of this extension but when I want run create extension command it tell me Server is version 9.5, library is version 9.4. Is there any way to install compatible version of extension on OS X?

Comment: If you insist on using beta versions, you will probably have to install from source. And fix the conflicts. Or wait till your packager does the dirty work.

Comment: Or hire someone on the PostGIS team to compile the extension for you if you're not comfortable doing so yourself.

Comment: @CraigRinger I compiled that myself and now it works like a charm, thanks for your advice!

Comment: @ehsandotnet Good on you for doing it.